# c# Replace openfileDialog to a none gui stream

Tags: c#, stream, openfiledialog

I am trying to separate the MIME gui from the code i need. I am almost there just one more gui element i dont know how to replace. This element is the openfiledialog. Here a code snippet.

Program.cs

```
var sfd = new OpenFileDialog();
sfd.FileName = "C:\\eml\\" + validOutputFilename;

try
{
    var writer = new MimeMessageWriter();
    using (var fs = sfd.OpenFile()) writer.Write(message, fs);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //ignore
    // need to log
}
```

message is an IMessage. A class created to store the information about an eml file. The open file dialog is allowing you to put in the file name with an eml extension and that is all. write.Write expects an IMessage and a stream. Inside writer.Write the file is being written  The only part of the file that uses this code is when the file itself is writen at the end and write out any attachments. Here are those code snippets.

*MimeMessageWriter

-the attachment uses it here

```
var embeddedMessage = attachment.OpenAsMessage();
var messageWriter = new MimeMessageWriter();
var msgStream = new MemoryStream();
messageWriter.Write(embeddedMessage, msgStream);

var messageAttachment = ew DotNetOpenMail.FileAttachment(msgStream.ToArray());
messageAttachment.ContentType = "message/rfc822";
messageAttachment.FileName = filename + ".eml";

outMessage.AddMixedAttachment(messageAttachment);
```

-write out the file part of the file

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
sw.Write(outMessage.ToDataString());
```

I want to replace openFileDialog with something that will allow me to pass the filename to write out file in the MimeMessageWriter

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
using (var fs = sfd.OpenFile()) writer.Write(message, fs);
```

with

```
string fileName = @"c:\eml\myAttachment.eml";
using ( FileStream fs = new FileStream( fileName, FileMode.CreateNew ) )
{
   writer.Write( message, fs )
}
```

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/47ek66wy.aspx